# IOS UIBarButtonItem works fine while UIButton causes Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to implement a custom navigation bar button item, I have a selector when user clicks to bar item a function is called.
If I set bar item to `UIBarButtonItem` it just works fine but I have to use a custom Image for the button without borders and appropriated size.

so in viewdidload I call

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //gear button on navigation Bar
    UIImage* imageback2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICON - Gear-BarstyleItem@2x.png"];
    CGRect frameimgback2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);

    UIButton *backButton2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimgback2];
    [backButton2 setBackgroundImage:imageback2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton2 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(setColorButtonTapped:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton2];


    UIBarButtonItem *btn3 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:imageback2 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(setColorButtonTapped:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn2;
}

#pragma mark Callbacks

- (IBAction)setColorButtonTapped:(id)sender{
    if (_colorPicker == nil) {
        self.colorPicker = [[ColorPickerController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _colorPicker.delegate = self;
        self.colorPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_colorPicker];
    }
    [self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

this gives me:

```
-[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9466620
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9466620'
```

If I set

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn2;
```

to

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn3;
```

It works fine but button have borders and background color and smaller size of image

So why it gives me error and how can I make this button a custom button?

Edit:

When I add a void function like

```
- (void)gearTapped{
    [self setColorButtonTapped:self];
}
```

and change selector at button it does not give any error but it shows popUp only one line an in the middle of the screen

```
[backButton2 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(gearTapped)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

[image]

It normally should work like this but with an custom button
[image]

Comment: Its work 4 me too { beginning with this iphone code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161909/how-to-use-storyboard-to-make-popover-that-can-be-used-in-code }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a `UIButton` instance as the `sender` argument to your action. Then passing `sender` as a parameter to a method expecting a `UIBarButtonItem` instance here:

```
[self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

If you are going to use the `sender` argument in your actions, you should make separate actions for the two different classes of objects. Like:

```
- (void)loadColorPicker
{
    if (_colorPicker == nil) {
        self.colorPicker = [[ColorPickerController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _colorPicker.delegate = self;
        self.colorPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_colorPicker];
    }
}
- (void)colorBarButtonItemTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self loadColorPicker];
    [self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

- (void)colorButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self loadColorPicker];
    [self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Then where you assign the targets and actions:

```
[backButton2 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(colorButtonTapped:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *btn3 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:imageback2 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(colorBarButtonItemTapped:)];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow you. But I'll edit my answer to be a little more explicit.

Comment: could you be more specific about it or give me an example? for example when I write a void function and call it in the button `-(void)popUp{ [self setColorButtonTapped:self]}`and change selector at button `[backButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(popUp)` this does not give me an error but shows the popUp only oneline and in middle of screen

Comment: @MordFustang let me know if this explains things a little more clearly.

Comment: It didnt solve problem exactly but at least It doesnt give any errors It works like oicture in the question, thanks though

Comment: @MordFustang Thanks for accepting. Are you having that issue with the zero-height popover? Can you update your question to indicate what your **current** code is exactly so I can see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView* btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: backButton2.bounds];
[btnView addSubview: backButton2];

UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnView];

//in case you are not using arc
[btnView release];
```

Cheers...

Comment: that gives me error also `-[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa35ba50`

Comment: Try to create a button as a button with custom type. `UIButton* backButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = frameimgback2;`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably because you should not initialize a `UIButton` using `alloc`/`initWithFrame` but with its `buttonWithType:` designed initializer (and set its frame separately, then).